# Specific Endpoint: Access Denied (no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header) on API Request in React/Redux App with Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, redux

I cannot access a custom heroku API endpoint in a react/redux app. The heroku endpoint loads up fine in a browser, and I can see the network request coming back on my console, so it seems something in my app itself is preventing it from returning.

It's the classic 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' error, but what's perplexing is that I can use another endpoint (such as openweather's API) and don't get this error.

Do I need to use Express or other middleware to deal with Heroku specifically? I'm creating a store with ReduxPromise middleware right now and am using Axios to make the request. Or is there a server side configuration on Heroku that might change this?

Thanks for your help, pretty new to react/redux/node =)

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue, you need to add a cors configuration into your API request and accept the origins on the server side using access-control-allow-origin header and accepting the referrer url of the request.

These are my configuration options when using redux-api to make the requests, look at the documentation for your specific framework:

```
export const baseOptions = {
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers
}
```

Comment: It turned out this was not a client-side issue but server side. The server response didn't include the proper CORS headers.